# Failed to load spaCy model 'en_core_web_sm'

Tags: python, spacy

Being complete python novice, I am trying to learn some spaCy basics. Problem is, I can not load any models.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community(MVSC), Windows 7, Python 3.7.5., pip 19.2.3 spaCy has been installed via pip on Python 3.7 (64-bit) environment.

(1) when I run in MVSC:

```py
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
```

I am getting: `“OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.”`

(2) When I run the same code in IDLE Python 3.7 (64-bit)
I am getting the same error as in (1).
Within modules list, I can see there is spaCy. Via “help(SPACY)” it lists “PACKAGE CONTENTS”, there is no word like “model”; FILE is “c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages\spacy_*init*_.py”

(3) When I run in CMD with Admin privileges `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`
I am getting: `“No module named spacy”`. When listing modules via python>help()>modules; I can see the list of available modules, but there is no module spaCy.

(4) For the other trials in MVSC, I created a new 64bit Python environment, successfully installed spaCy via “install spacy (2.3.2)” => ran the above code, and got the same errors as above.

Comment: Try to run `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm` as normal user (not CMD as admin) You probably installed spaCy as a normal user and not as an admin.

Comment: I tried, it did not help

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked the project's GitHub repo? There is a closed issue that seems to be close (minus the spaCy version you're using)

https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/4577

> When you run `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`, it will pretty
> much execute the same thing (pip install [link]), with pip running in
> a subprocess. The download also takes care of finding you the right
> version of the model and outputting helpful messages.
>
> However, if the pip executed with python3 -m pip install isn't the
> same as pip3 install, it may execute the wrong pip and install the
> model in a different environment. In most environments, this is not a
> problem – but if it is, installing the models directly via the link is
> a fine solution.

Comment: Tx, When I run CMD as admin with indicated code&link “python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_sm pip3 install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0.tar.gz” => it loads the model but, I am getting “Running setup.py install for blis: finished with status ‘error’ “. I installed Python 64 bit, launched the same CMD code&link and I am again receiving the same error. ython Shell/Vis Studio environment 64 bit, really works as 64 bit. So finally no success, seems there is issue with Blis and Python 64, not sure what to do.

Answer (score 2):

this is happening because spacy vocab for English is missing, try to activate the python environment and run :
`python -m spacy download en`
this will download English vocabulary.

It worked for me, hope it works for you. :)

Thanks Regards